# Bounding Box Predicted Values from ONNX models Questions (Face Detection)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, onnx

I have an assignment of loading a bunch of onnx models (which achieve object detection in images) and evaluate which ones work the best.

ALl the models have 6 outputs having 3 scales being **8, 16, and 32** for the *bounding box values* and *scores*. After inferring each model by **300 validation images** I obtained the predictions and split them according to their scales for e.g. `m1_pred_score_8, m1_pred_score_16, m1_pred_score_32, m1_pred_bbox_8, m1_pred_bbox_16, m1_pred_bbox_32`. FYI the 300 validation images had to be rescaled to *640x640*, converted to *CHW format*, standardising the pixels by a *mean* and *standard deviation* of *127.5*.

I then applied **confidence score thresholding** to remove any inaccurate bounding boxes by their score, and afterwards I applied **IOU thresholding** to further filter the predicted bounding boxes by the IOU threshold.

My **first question** is: The predicted bounding box values seem to be too small when compared to the actual true bounding box values. For example:

Predicted BBOXES:
`(array([0.95482224, 1.2450836 , 1.1954792 , 1.5730847 ], dtype=float32), (array([0.93208635, 1.100327  , 1.0652213 , 1.5531455 ], dtype=float32)`

True BBOXES:
`[(301.0, 157.0, 515.0, 633.0), (536.0, 262.0, 922.0, 849.0)]'`

Should the predicted bounding box values be this small?

My **second question** is: The predicted bounding boxes are not being drawn on the images. I tried to draw them by cv2.rectangle() and I think something is wrong with how I enter the x1,x2,y1,y2 coordinates. What can I do?

My **third question** is: Is there a ready made function to calculate the IOU between bounding boxes as I tried the cv2.dnn.nmsboxes() function but it wasn't working so I created my own? I am not sure if it is correct. Also, if for an image there are multiple bounding boxes which boxes will be used for the IOU ?

My **four question** is: Should I re-combine the bounding boxes of different scales when evaluating the models or should I keep them separate and compare at each scale (8, 16, 32)?

My **last question** is: What are the best metrics to use to evaluate face detection models? I'm guessing IOU is one of them.

## Regarding Question 1:

Here is the function to pre-process the validation images:

```
def pre_process_image(img, size):
    #convert to RGB
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    #resizing image to specific size
    img = cv2.resize(img, size)
    #adjusting pixel values by means of standardisation
    img_float = img.astype(np.float32)
    img_float -= 127.5 # subtracting the mean (127.5) from each channel
    img_float /= 127.5 # dividing by the standard deviation (127.5) 
    img_float = np.clip(img_float, 0, 255) #clipping pixel values to the range [0, 255]
    #img_stand = (img_float * 255).astype(np.uint8) #converting pixel values back to integer
    #converting image to chw format
    img_chw = np.transpose(img_float , (2, 0, 1)) # 2 - channel dimension, 0 - height dimension, 1 - width dimension
    
    return img_chw
```

## Regarding Question 2:

Here is the function to draw the predicted bounding boxes on the images:

```
def draw_bounding_boxes(images, all_bboxes):
    img_nums = obtain_img_numbers(all_bboxes)
    for num in img_nums:
        img = convert_image_to_hwc(images[num])
        img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        same_img_bboxes = combine_bbox_by_image(all_bboxes, num)
        
        for bbox in same_img_bboxes:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox[0]
            cv2.rectangle(img_bgr, (int(x1*640), int(y1*640)), (int(x2*640), int(y2*640)), (0, 255, 0), 5)  # Green rectangle
            
        img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img_rgb = np.clip(img_rgb, 0, 1)
        plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        plt.title("Image: " + str(num))
        plt.imshow(img_rgb)
        plt.axis('off') 
        plt.show()
```

## Regarding Question 3:

Here are the functions to perform IOU:

```
def calculate_iou(bbox1, bbox2):
    
    # Extract coordinates of the bounding boxes
    if isinstance(bbox1, tuple) == True:
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = bbox1
    elif isinstance(bbox2, tuple) == True:
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = bbox2
    
    x1 = max(bbox1[0], bbox2[0])
    y1 = max(bbox1[1], bbox2[1])
    x2 = min(bbox1[2], bbox2[2])
    y2 = min(bbox1[3], bbox2[3])

    # Calculate the area of intersection
    intersection_area = max(0, x2 - x1) * max(0, y2 - y1)

    # Calculate the area of the bounding boxes
    bbox1_area = (bbox1[2] - bbox1[0]) * (bbox1[3] - bbox1[1])
    bbox2_area = (bbox2[2] - bbox2[0]) * (bbox2[3] - bbox2[1])

    # Calculate the IoU
    iou = intersection_area / (bbox1_area + bbox2_area - intersection_area)

    return iou
```

```
def apply_iou_threshold(bboxes, scores, iou_threshold):
    # Initialize two empty lists to store the filtered bounding boxes and their scores
    filtered_bboxes = []
    filtered_scores = []

    for i in range(len(bboxes)):  # Iterate over the images
        # Get the bounding boxes and scores for the current image
        bbox = bboxes[i]
        score = scores[i]
        # Add the first bounding box since it's the best score within the same image
        if not filtered_bboxes:
            filtered_bboxes.append(bbox)
            filtered_scores.append(score)
        else:
            # Check for IoU with the previously added bounding box
            iou = calculate_iou(bbox[0], filtered_bboxes[-1][0])
            #print(iou)    
            if iou >= iou_threshold:
                filtered_bboxes.append(bbox)
                filtered_scores.append(score)

    return filtered_bboxes, filtered_scores
```